# Kinect skeleton tracking

Tags: kinect

I am working with Kinect and I implemented a skeleton tracking mechanism to keep joint trajectories of a sequence of human gait with single kinect. The problem is with the accuracy of the mesurments. I want to overcome occlusion and jitter problems. I found some filter implementations to deal with jittering (more advanced than average filters). But occlusion is more difficult. Is there an good open source project for skeleton tracking with good results (more accurate). Microsoft sdk or openni it doesn't matter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did a gait recognition using Kinect and I used microsoft official sdk. The accuracy of measurements is based on your calculation. Check this [as example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/380152/Kinect-for-Windows-Find-User-Height-Accurately).